# Wrapping Events in Anonymous Functions - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been reading up on anonymous javascript functions and have a general question about using them with event listeners via jquery.

I have the following event listener that will do some stuff upon the submission of a form.

```
if(sky === 'blue') {
    $('#my-form').on('submit', function(){
        //do some stuff
        $('#my-div').show();
    })
}
```

Would it make any difference (i.e., pros & cons, things that could go wrong, etc.) if I were to declare it as-is in my javascript file or should I be wrapping it in an anonymous function like so

```
 $(function() {
    if(sky === 'blue') {
    //do my stuff
 }
```

Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273185/what-are-the-benefits-to-using-anonymous-functions-instead-of-named-functions-fo

Comment: Without using $(function() {}); there are chances to get error pf $ is undefined. So it's better to use this.

Comment: No, this is not similar to the question Tasos K. suggested

Comment: @AR_Web how? If `$` is undefined, it will error in either case.

Comment: OP, what do __you__ see as the functional difference between those scenarios?

Comment: I'm studying up on this now, can't draw any conclusions with my limited knowledge now

Answer (score 2):

If you're not declaring any vars or functions **and** you make sure your code will execute after the dom is ready it doesn't make any difference.

**BUT** the common experience is that maybe you are sure those premises are true now, but someday somebody will break one of them, then you'll propably have a problem (a leak, a conflict, whatever).

As an advice, I would tell you to wrap your code into a Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).